# Replace column name by referring to a table file in R

Tags: r

I want to replace column name by referring to a table.

Below is my question.

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
     a b c d e
row1 1 2 3 4 5
 "), header = TRUE)


Newtitle <- read.table(textConnection("
id   id2
 a  kitty
 d  oren
 g  dyron
 "), header = TRUE)
```

If the Newtitle$id match with column name in data,

then I want to replace data's column name by Newtitle$id2, otherwise just keep the original column name.

```
    kitty b c oren e
row1    1 2 3    4 5
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to be careful with the difference between factors and characters.

```
Newtitle$id <- as.character(Newtitle$id)
Newtitle$id2 <- as.character(Newtitle$id2)
rownames(Newtitle) <- Newtitle$id
replaced <- names(data) %in% Newtitle$id
names(data)[replaced] <- Newtitle[names(data)[replaced], "id2"]
```