# How to replace column names in data set using a csv lookup file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `RStudio` and I have the following `R` codes running (which retrieves Stock prices):

```
if (!require(BatchGetSymbols)) install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')

library(BatchGetSymbols)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 60
last.date <- Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'daily'
# set tickers
tickers <- c('AAPL','BIDU')

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(l.out$df.tickers, aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = 'free_y') 
print(p)
```

Output of `p` is shown below:

[image: ggplot2 screenshot]

I would like the `ggplot2` graph to display the company name instead of the ticker symbol. (That is, APPLE instead of "AAPL", BAIDU instead of "BIDU").

I have a `csv` file which contains the list of code names (tickers) and their relevant company names. How can I replace the tickers with the Company Names so that they are displayed in my `ggplot2` graph?

I have tried the following (still giving the same graph as before):

```
if (!require(BatchGetSymbols)) install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')

library(BatchGetSymbols)

# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 60
last.date <- Sys.Date()
freq.data <- 'daily'
# set tickers
tickers <- c('AAPL','BIDU')

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date, 
                         freq.data = freq.data,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                  'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()

codes_list <- read.csv("codes_list.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

codes_list$code <- as.character(codes_list$code)
codes_list$desc <- as.character(codes_list$desc)
rownames(codes_list) <- codes_list$code
replaced <- names(l.out$df.tickers) %in% codes_list$code
names(l.out$df.tickers)[replaced] <- codes_list[names(l.out$df.tickers)[replaced], "desc"]


library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(l.out$df.tickers, aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close))
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = 'free_y') 
print(p)
```

An extract of the "codes_list.csv" file is shown below:

```
code       desc
AAPL       APPLE
BIDU       BAIDU
```

I tried the above based on the solution provided here: [Replace column name by referring to a table file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671271/replace-column-name-by-referring-to-a-table-file-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a join on the two datasets to get the corresponding desc.

```r
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

codes_list <- read.csv("codes_list.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

inner_join(l.out$df.tickers, codes_list, by = c('ticker' = 'code')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~desc, scales = 'free_y')
```

Let me know if this helps!

EDIT: `l.out` is a list and the relevant object is `l.out$df.tickers`

Comment: I get the following error: Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "list".
I guess that is because "l.out" is a list.

Comment: Ok your answer helped me to find the error. In your : inner_join codes, it should be "l.out$df.tickers" and "codes_list" instead of "code_list".
Please correct accordingly in your soultion and I will give the vote. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to reflect that. Would it great if you can accept it. Glad it helped!